# How can i get https responses on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https

I get this exception when trying to fetch response for an https link

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Could not verify SSL certificate for: https://[...link...]

Below is the code I use. What am I doing wrong?

```
URL productsURL = new URL(link + authenticationExtension);
URLConnection connection = productsURL.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + userNamePasswordB64);
connection.connect();       
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [`FetchOptions doNotValidateCertificate`](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/FetchOptions.html#doNotValidateCertificate%28%29) method.  There is a note about this in the [URL Fetch docs](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview.html#Secure_Connections_and_HTTPS).